# Question around SOQL and object model fields

Tags: soql, workbench

I have a question around the SOQL query below.

`SELECT Assignee.Name, Assignee.Profile.Name, Assignee.UserRole.Name, Assignee.Profile.UserLicense.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSet.Name = 'Lightning_Experience_User'`

Why is it that I have to use **assignee.blah** and why can't I use **user.blah** in the query?

My query returns the result below, notice the tab shows **User.Name, User.UserRole.**

Whereas I can use the object API names for other objects such as Profile and UserLicense.

[image]

I hope that makes sense what I am trying to explain.

Thank you

Comment: The `PermissionSetAssignment` object does not have any field by the name `User`. The field reference to User object is named as `Assignee`.

Comment: When I look at the documentation here, I don't see a Assignee field rather the AssigneeId.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_permissionsetassignment.htm

Comment: Ok, I THINK I see where I got confused I didn't know about the 'Relationship Name' Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PermissionSetAssignment object Represents the association between a User and a PermissionSet. This object is available in API version 22.0 and later.

PermissionSetAssignment object have the relationship field with Assignee instead of user to the user object, that is the reason you can't able to use the user in the soql query of PermissionSetAssignment object.

check the [PermissionSetAssignment object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_permissionsetassignment.htm)